# Windows 10 backup procedure

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, backup

I have the following scenario and have tried backup programs to test and have ran into many issues. So I’m wondering if Windows can get me out of this jam and it would be free if it can.

I have a Windows 10 machine with my VirtualBox which is my development environment. My hardware that I can do backups on is a secondary internal drive that is the same size as the main drive and a 2TB external drive from Seagate. I need a 100% way of doing a backup so I don’t lose my stuff again. I would like to have at least two backups at all times - full image, bootable in case the entire OS goes down.

Questions

1. How can I configure Windows 10 backup tools to do a backup of the entire hard drive, alternating between the drive - one internal and one external. I could put more hard drives in if needed as well but to simplify I wanted to see if this can be done.
2. If the above can’t be done what do you recommend? And preferably the steps on whatever software you are recommending. I have looked for various software to do this and tested many of them and each failed at some crucial part.
3. Will Windows image the disk and will it be bootable or is that what the system repair disk is used for? Maybe explain the process of hard drive goes down completely - how do I get the image file that is on one of the drives back on the C Drive?
4. Will a system image take care of the VirtualBox program and all the machines? I think it will but not sure.

Comment: Sounds like a good RAID system would do you well.

Comment: @EricF - The use of a RAID Array by itself is not a backup solution.  Its a storage solution, but you still need perform a backups, of the RAID Array itself.

Comment: @Ramhound How is that not a backup? You have a physical copy that can exist if the first disappears. Isn't that the definition of being a backup?

Comment: @EricF - I suppose having another copy of the file, does statisfy the requirements, of being a backup.  You also introduce all the negatives of a RAID Array, like preventing data loss if a single drive goes out by picking RAID 0.  Which is the reason I suggest you have to backup the RAID, or NAS, or any storage location.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh I agree with that as well. Just saying a RAID may be something he is after

Comment: @EricF - If you do a Raid system, is one of the disk bootable? Sorry very unfamiliar with Raid storage.

Comment: Well depending on your RAID setup... If you did a RAID 1 setup then one drive is an exact copy of the other.. meaning booting up is identical on both

Comment: @EricF - it appears Windows 10 has something similar - [website](http://www.pcgamer.com/how-set-raid-1-windows-and-linux-2015/) Does that sound right?

Comment: Something like that would work... always know that hardware raids are better than software raids. Most modern BIOS's allow you to do it in them... you might want to look at if yours can

Comment: thanks @EricF and others.  I will give this a try. In theory once I have it set up, I should be able to unplug my hard drive from motherboard, mimicking drive failure, and the other drive should boot and I should see no difference. At least if I'm thinking through the test the right way....

Comment: I posted an answer that helps introduce you to RAID types

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after a solid back up solution.  I would recommend using a RAID setup of some form to help you out.

**A brief explanation of RAID types:**

•RAID 0 is used to boost a server's performance. It's also known as "disk striping." With RAID 0, data is written across multiple disks. This means the work that the computer is doing is handled by multiple disks rather than just one, increasing performance because multiple drives are reading and writing data, improving disk I/O. A minimum of two disks is required. Both software and hardware RAID support RAID 0, as do most controllers. The downside is that there is no fault tolerance. If one disk fails, then that affects the entire array and the chances for data loss or corruption increases.

•RAID 1 is a fault-tolerance configuration known as "disk mirroring." With RAID 1, data is copied seamlessly and simultaneously, from one disk to another, creating a replica, or mirror. If one disk gets fried, the other can keep working. It's the simplest way to implement fault tolerance and it's relatively low cost.

The downside is that RAID 1 causes a slight drag on performance. RAID 1 can be implemented through either software or hardware. A minimum of two disks is required for RAID 1 hardware implementations. With software RAID 1, instead of two physical disks, data can be mirrored between volumes on a single disk. One additional point to remember is that RAID 1 cuts total disk capacity in half: If a server with two 1TB drives is configured with RAID 1, then total storage capacity will be 1TB not 2TB.

•RAID 5 is by far the most common RAID configuration for business servers and enterprise NAS devices. This RAID level provides better performance than mirroring as well as fault tolerance. With RAID 5, data and parity (which is additional data used for recovery) are striped across three or more disks. If a disk gets an error or starts to fail, data is recreated from this distributed data and parity block— seamlessly and automatically. Essentially, the system is still operational even when one disk kicks the bucket and until you can replace the failed drive. Another benefit of RAID 5 is that it allows many NAS and server drives to be "hot-swappable" meaning in case a drive in the array fails, that drive can be swapped with a new drive without shutting down the server or NAS and without having to interrupt users who may be accessing the server or NAS. It's a great solution for fault tolerance because as drives fail (and they eventually will), the data can be rebuilt to new disks as failing disks are replaced. The downside to RAID 5 is the performance hit to servers that perform a lot of write operations. For example, with RAID 5 on a server that has a database that many employees access in a workday, there could be noticeable lag.

•RAID 6 is also used frequently in enterprises. It's identical to RAID 5, except it's an even more robust solution because it uses one more parity block than RAID 5. You can have two disks die and still have a system be operational.

•RAID 10 is a combination of RAID 1 and 0 and is often denoted as RAID 1+0. It combines the mirroring of RAID 1 with the striping of RAID 0. It's the RAID level that gives the best performance, but it is also costly, requiring twice as many disks as other RAID levels, for a minimum of four. This is the RAID level ideal for highly utilized database servers or any server that's performing many write operations. RAID 10 can be implemented as hardware or software, but the general consensus is that many of the performance advantages are lost when you use software RAID 10.

As was pointed out in the comments, a RAID is not fully safe.. just better than a single disk. Many modern motherboards have the capability of doing a RAID from within the BIOS. If not then there are many software RAID options available for Windows.

Comment: Raid 0 is not a backup solution, in fact it is not raid at all.

Comment: @Moab That is correct but since the asker didn't seem familiar with RAID types I listed it to try and help clarify what he is after.